# How to add Sunshine Lesson_4 starter code to my App

Tags: android

I'm following Udacity's Android app development tutorial at the moment, till lesson 3 i was writing the given code by my self, also remaining the app from initial project name:"Sunshine" to:"My_first_dev"... but in the Lesson_4 they given us a starter code from Github :

> https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/4.02_start_code_for_lesson_4

1. They don't explain if i have to add it to my existing project ?
2. I guess, i have to "add it" to my existing project, so i download it, but didn't know how to add it ?
3. I open it in a new project and have :"Failed to sync Gradle project 'Sunshine-Version-2-4.02_start_code_for_lesson_4'"

Comment: You shouldn't add it to an existing project, it looks like an independent application that you do File > Open from existing sources, or something like that

Comment: i did it but i had this message : "Failed to sync Gradle project 'Sunshine-Version-2-4.02_start_code_for_lesson_4'"; it seems to be a gradle wrapper problem ! am looking a solution for this message, so if you have ?

Comment: Sorry, don't have a solution. If you have Gradle sync problems, then some other error message exists somewhere with more description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also took that course. It's easy to fix.

First, gradle is not building your project because you haven't specified your weather api key. Once you have opened android studio with the project that you downloaded, go to the gradle.properties file. There you have to add the following line:

```
MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey ="whatever your api key is"
```

Once you do that, your project will be ready to install in your phone/emulator.

If they posted a link to the starter code for lesson 4, then your code is ready to follow along with the lesson.

If later on, the tell you to grab the starter code for another lesson, all you have to do is checkout the correct branch using git.

Just look at the bottom of your window, you'll see a button with the name "terminal". Click on it.

Then, just type the following statement:

```
git checkout <name of the branch>
```

And you will be ready to follow along. Remember that you will have to change your api key every time that you checkout a new branch.

Hope this helps.